# Dymola print translation log to file

Tags: debugging, logging, dymola

Dymola shows some interesting statistics and information about the translation process in the message window -> translation tab.
I am interested for example in the number and size of linear and nonlinear systems, and I turned on additional info using the flags:

- `Advanced.LogStructuredEvaluation = true;`
- `Advanced.PrintFailureToDifferentiate = true;`
- `Advanced.Translation.Log.FailureToInline = true;`

Is there an option to print all the information shown in the message window translation tab into a file? Maybe even preserving the structure that allows folding/unfolding in the message window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before translation you can use:

```
Advanced.TranslationInCommandLog = true;
```

and afterwards:

```
savelog("logfile.txt");
```

I don't think we can directly store the translation-log, but this should do the job.